# SPI.transfer(buffer, size) does not send data from buffer

Tags: arduino-uno, spi

I am having trouble getting `SPI.transfer(buffer, size)` to work as expected.

Here is the code:

```
// inslude the SPI library:
#include <SPI.h>


// set pin 10 as the slave select for the digital pot:
const int slaveSelectPin = 10;

uint16_t SPI_message = 0xABCD;

void setup() {
  // set the slaveSelectPin as an output:
  pinMode(slaveSelectPin, OUTPUT);
  // initialize SPI:
  SPI.begin();

}

void loop() {

  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(14000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));
  SPI.transfer(0xEF);
  SPI.transfer(&SPI_message, 2);
  SPI.endTransaction();

  delayMicroseconds(300);

}
```

Here is the output of logic analyzer:

[image]

As can be seen the call for `SPI.Transfer(0xEF)` works as expected. However `SPI.transfer(&SPI_message,2)` sends 0x0000 instead of 0xABCD on the bus.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: `SPI.transfer(&SPI_message,2)` is destructive. The buffer is updated with the received values.

Comment: I assume this is Arduino? Can you decrease SPI clock - currently you seem to be at the limit of your logic analyser. Does it work if you split the second transfer into two 1B transfers?  --- What Mikael said is probably the reason for your issue.

Comment: @MikaelPatel But still I should be able to see 0xABCD on my MOSI line on the SPI bus? I am not trying here to read data from a variable, but I am observing signals on the line of the SPI.

Comment: Only the first time `loop` is executed, then SPI_message is overwritten and zeroes are sent. Try reinitialising it to 0xabcd in `loop`.

Comment: @domen Exactly! this is what I was overseeing! Now it works.

Comment: @MikaelPatel your comment answers my question, together with explanation from domen. If you convert it into an answer, I can accept it. Thank you both for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SPI.transfer(&SPI_message,2)` is unfortunately destructive. The buffer is updated with the received values. There is a SPI member function[1] that can be used for 16-bit data; `SPI.transfer16(SPI_message)`.

To correct your sketch either initialize the buffer before each call (as recommended by @domen) or use the 16-bit transfer function.

There are other SPI APIs that included non-destructive transfer function e.g. read/write. Please see [2].

Cheers!

Ref.

1. https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPITransfer
2. https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Arduino-SPI/blob/master/src/SPI.h#L137